# Ternary condition with equal to not working

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to check userStatus and currentUser while comparing it with a value but it is not working and on the other hand if I put not equal to then it works.

I want to compare the value like mentioned below:-

```
body: currentUser == null ?
        Center(child: Splash())
            :currentUser.userStatus == 'isBlocked'
            ? BlockUser():
        Center(
          child: Container(),
```

And on the other hand if I put != sign then it works:-

```
body: currentUser != null ?
            Center(child: Splash())
                :currentUser.userStatus != 'isBlocked'
                ? BlockUser():
            Center(
              child: Container(),
```

But here I want to compare the values which are stored in database and then show the desired result. Pls help.

Comment: Did you try nested ternary operator with brackets?

Comment: what is the output of section scenario

Comment: The two alternatives you have written are not equivalent. Second one should fail hard if currentUser is null. Then you would try to check the userStatus property on a null value, which will not be a good thing...

Comment: @StewieGriffin, Yes with brackets also it is same.

Comment: @RobertSandberg, then how it supposed to be done? If the user is null for some reason then I want to send user to Splash Screen and if it is not null but blocked by the admin then I want to send user to Blocked Screen and keep him away from the app.

Comment: Yeah but now you are checking if currentuser is not null, and if that is the case then returning Center(child: Splash). Ternary operators are best suited for small and very simple logic. Write a method instead to handle your cases. The code will be more readable and simple mistakes like this wouldn't happen as easily.

Answer (score 1):

As I hinted about in the comment to your question. I would suggest to ditch the ternary operator and write a method instead.

Ternary operators are best suited for small and very simple logic.
The code will be more readable and simple mistakes wouldn't happen as easily. Instead do something like this:

```
body: myAwesomeUserChecker(),
...
```

With the method:

```
Widget myAwesomeUserChecker() {
  if (currentUser == null) {
    return Center(child: Splash());
  }
  if (currentUser.userStatus == 'isBlocked') {
    return BlockUser();
  }
  return Center(child: Container());
}
```

Ps. This matches the first option that you wrote, but which you said didn't do what you wanted... The second option you wrote somehow did what you expected, but logically that alternative seemed flawed. So, if what I wrote here doesn't give you your expected outcome, then I would assume the fault might be somewhere else, or you'd have to provide more information so that the case can be better understood.

Comment: yes, thanks for this, but it didn't work. and second option I mentioned only to share that I checked it like != and it showed the desired screens but ultimately I am looking for this only what you answered but I dont know why this also not worked.

Comment: The origin of fthe problem is not the ternary operator. But it kind of became your problem because nesting them could get hard to read. In your case, your second option became erroneous. I suggest that you use breakpoints to find where things go wrong in your case. You have provided too little information for anyone else to help.

Comment: This is Home Screen and after this there are just Bottom Navigation items with index which switches from one tab to another and nothing else and then I don't know what else to share more.

Answer (score 0):

Please define your expected behavior more precisely. If we better understand your desired outcome, we can help better.

I tried to unify the indentation and punctuation of your code and added some comments. Does this accurately represent the behavior you intended and it is still not behaving as the comments below indicate?

```
body: currentUser == null ?
  // If currentUser == null, Splash() will be centered
  // userStatus will not even be checked
  Center(child: Splash()) :

  // Else (currentUser != null), userStatus will be checked
  currentUser.userStatus == 'isBlocked' ?
    // If currentUser != null and userStatus == 'isBlocked' then BlockUser()
    BlockUser() :
    // Else (currentUser != and userStatus != 'isBlocked') center Container()
    Center(child: Container()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, before making this logic, try to print the value of both currentUser and the value currentUser.userStatus to know what the currentUser has and what the currentUser.userStatus returns. After that, you may make a logic using simple if-else statements. Once you get success in that, then convert it to ternary condition.